# test file upload with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, testing, file-upload

**Is it possible to test the file-upload in your own computer with an emulated server, or it's only possible to a real server???**

If i try to upload a file, i get the message 'The download could not be saved. Please, try again.'. (The message is coming from my own DownloadController.) Nothing is saved to upload-path or stored in the database.

So CakePHP runs a build-in Web-Server. I thougt i can upload a file to my own computer (i know its not a real upload, but there is my file, the web-server, the webroot with upload-path...)
But maybe i'm totally wrong trying this??? Really don't find anything on web...

In my application i want to give the users opportunity to download files.
So what i've done yet.

Installed the upload-plugin Josegonzalez.

DownloadsTables.php

```
$this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
            'file' => [
                    'path' => 'webroot{DS}downloads{DS}',
                    'fields' => [
                            // if these fields or their defaults exists
                            // the values will be set.
                            'dir' => 'file_dir', //defaults to 'dir'
                            'size' => 'file_size', //defaults to 'size'
                            'type' => 'file_type', //defaults to 'type'
                    ],
            ],              
    ]);
```

In TemplateDownloads/add.ctp

```
<?= $this->Form->create('Download', ['type' => 'file']) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Download') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('Download.name');
        echo $this->Form->control('Download.file', ['type' => 'file']);
        echo $this->Form->control('Download.file_dir', ['type' => 'hidden']);
        //echo $this->Form->control('meetings._ids', ['options' => $meetings]);
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

In DownloadsController.php

```
public function add()
{
    $download = $this->Downloads->newEntity();
    // @ToDo download auf Server aktivieren

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //debug ($this->request);
        //debug ($this->Downloads);
        $download = $this->Downloads->patchEntity($download, $this->request->getData());
        debug ($download);
        debug ($this->addBehavior);
        if ($this->Downloads->save($download)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The download has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The download could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $meetings = $this->Downloads->Meetings->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('download', 'meetings'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['download']);
}
```

bootstrap.php

```
Plugin::load('Josegonzalez/Upload');
```

So I'm waiting hopefully for your help and thank you for your advice

---

Edit:

My CakePHP Version is 3.4.6

Entitiy before saving

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Download) {

'Download' => [
    'name' => 'test1',
    'file_dir' => '',
    'file' => [
        'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpiBp9GI',
        'error' => (int) 0,
        'name' => 'test1',
        'type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'size' => (int) 15
    ]
],
'[new]' => true,
'[accessible]' => [
    '*' => true,
    'id' => false
],
'[dirty]' => [
    'Download' => true
],
'[original]' => [],
'[virtual]' => [],
'[errors]' => [],
'[invalid]' => [],
'[repository]' => 'Downloads'}
```

and after saving

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Download) {

'Download' => [
    'name' => 'test1',
    'file_dir' => '',
    'file' => [
        'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpiBp9GI',
        'error' => (int) 0,
        'name' => 'test1',
        'type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'size' => (int) 15
    ]
],
'file' => null,
'[new]' => true,
'[accessible]' => [
    '*' => true,
    'id' => false
],
'[dirty]' => [
    'Download' => true,
    'file' => true
],
'[original]' => [],
'[virtual]' => [],
'[errors]' => [],
'[invalid]' => [],
'[repository]' => 'Downloads'}
```

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt or lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)

Comment: 1. there's no need to pass `file_dir`, 2. debug your entity _after_ saving too, and show the results of before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heureka!!!

I found the solution after ca 4 days!

The problem is in TemplateDownloads/add.ctp 
Cake don't like in the Form-Control-command'Download.name'
It has to be only name without Download (it' declared allready in theForm-create-command!

So the correct TemplateDownloads/app.ctp

```
<div class="downloads form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
<?= $this->Form->create('Download', ['type' => 'file']) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Download') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('name');
        echo $this->Form->control('file', ['type' => 'file']);
        echo $this->Form->control('file_dir', ['type' => 'hidden']);
        echo $this->Form->control('meetings._ids', ['options' => $meetings]);
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

**So it is possible to test lokal a file-upload!! with CakePHP**